# Why can't I pass a value that matches a given enum to a function that accepts the said enum

Tags: rust

While learning Rust Enums, I stumbled upon a strange situation where I can't pass a value that matches a given enum to a function that accepts the said enum as argument:

```rust
enum Foo {
  Char(char),
  Boolean(bool)
}

fn do_something(value: Foo) {

}

fn main() {
  do_something('a'); // Type mismatch [E0308] expected `Foo`, but found `char` 
}
```

Ths official documentation clearly says that it should work: https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch06-01-defining-an-enum.html#enum-values

> We can then, for instance, define a function that takes any IpAddrKind:
>
> ```
>   fn route(ip_kind: IpAddrKind) {}
> ```
>
> And we can call this function with either variant:
>
> ```
>    route(IpAddrKind::V4);
>    route(IpAddrKind::V6);
> ```

Comment: Actually you do not call with a variant but with char. `do_something(Foo::Char('a'))` does what is explained in the documentation.

Comment: @CoronA isn't `Foo::Char('a')` exactly the same thing as `'a'` - i.e. a `char` instance?

Comment: No. Enums use a _discriminant_ (`Foo::Char`) to distinguish between different variants. The types contained within a variant are unrelated to the discriminant, you must always specify it.

Comment: For instance, you could have `enum Bar { A(bool), B(bool), C(bool) }` where all variants have the same field type.

Comment: Perhaps here you'd like to `impl From<char> for Foo` and then call as `do_something('a'.into())` or even redefine `fn do_something(value: impl Into<Foo>)`.

Comment: I have the feeling that I did not understand the concept of enum in Rust, which maybe says something about their official book. I'll get back to it, re-read and try to understand what I missed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An `enum` in Rust is a type whose instances consist of:

- a discriminant (*which* variant is this), and
- (optionally) some data associated with the variant.

Even if there is no data associated with a variant, the `enum` instance has some meaning. For instance:

```rust
enum Direction {
    Left,
    Right,
}
```

Then, `Direction::Left` is a value of type `Direction`. There are `enum`s where some of the variants have some data, for example:

```rust
enum DatabaseStorage {
    FilePath(String),
    Memory,
}
```

Note that `DatabaseStorage::FilePath("foo".to_string())` is not the same thing as `"foo".to_string()`. In this case, you could argue that there is only one way to "reasonably" convert a `String` to a `DatabaseStorage`, but Rust generally avoids implicit type conversions like this. What's more, there are enums like this:

```rust
enum Outcome {
    Error(String), // error message
    Success(String), // description of successful outcome
    InProgress(String, u8), // operation in progress and % done
}
```

Here, there are two very different variants, each of which stores some `String` data (and one which *also* stores a `u8` value). How would you expect Rust to figure out which one you meant? This is why, in your example, a `char` does not automatically work where an argument of type `Foo` is expected.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It is still not very clear what an enum brings that a classic object doesn't but not only is this not in the scope of the question, but I think it will become clearer as I learn the language. Still, your answer confirm one thing: I did not understand at all what an enum is and was falsely assuming that it was analoguous to an union type. Anyway, again thanks.